# Logging variables in Plumber

Tags: r, plumber

I have followed the Rstudio [example here for logging](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/08/13/plumber-logging/) for logging requests in Plumber (R API package) and would like to add other variables to the log. However, the `registerHooks` statement does not recognise global variables (`<<-`).

```
# Enable CORS Filtering
#' @filter auth_filter
auth_filter <- function(req, res) {
req_user <<- req$HEADERS['authorization'] %>% as.character()
req_tenant <<- req$HTTP_TENANT
}

pr$registerHooks(
list(
preroute = function() {
# Start timer for log info
tictoc::tic()
},
postroute = function(req, res) {
end <- tictoc::toc(quiet = TRUE)
# Log details about the request and the response
log_info('{convert_empty(req_user)} {convert_empty(req_tenant)} {convert_empty(req$REMOTE_ADDR)} "{convert_empty(req$HTTP_USER_AGENT)}" {convert_empty(req$HTTP_HOST)} {convert_empty(req$REQUEST_METHOD)} {convert_empty(req$PATH_INFO)} {convert_empty(res$status)} {round(end$toc - end$tic, digits = getOption("digits", 5))}')
}))
```

In the above example, `req_user` and `req_tenant` change for every request. The above example gives an error message, stating that `req_user` and `req_tenant` do not exist. I have also tried `preserialize` as an alternative to `postroute`. How can these variables be logged? The don't need to be global, this was just an additional attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need to store these as global variables. `req` itself is an environment that's passed along, so you should be able to access those variables in `req` directly in your `postroute`. I'm not sure if `HTTP_TENANT` does exist though at all. Have a look at debugging interactively, e.g. using `browser()` as shown at https://www.rplumber.io/articles/tips-and-tricks.html. Once you've stepped into the function, explore `req` and find what you need.

Comment: I have tried adding tenant and user name to req (pass-by-reference), but it doesn't work - username is decrypted from a bearer token so needs to be added to req in the filter. Using browser() reveals the variables are a part of req, but I think it has something to do with log_info and the string there, as it seems to not recognize the variables. Maybe it takes req from an earlier than the stage for postroute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error is produced because of the `convert_empty` function not being able to handle `null`'s or `na`'s.

I adjusted this function to handle null's or na's in case they do occur:

```
convert_empty <- function(string) {
  if (is.null(string) || is.na(string) || string == "") {
    "-"
  } else {
    string
  }
}
```

Using the sample `plumber.R` code that's produced in RStudio, this should work:

```
#Plumber.R file

library(plumber)
library(logger)

# Specify how logs are written
log_dir <- "logs"
if (!fs::dir_exists(log_dir)) fs::dir_create(log_dir)
log_appender(appender_tee(tempfile("plumber_", log_dir, ".log")))

#* Return the sum of two numbers
#* @param a The first number to add
#* @param b The second number to add
#* @post /sum
function(a, b) {
    as.numeric(a) + as.numeric(b)
}
```

Then we register the hooks as follows:

```
library(plumber)

pr <- plumb("plumber.R")

convert_empty <- function(string) {
  if (is.null(string) || is.na(string) || string == "") {
    "-"
  } else {
    string
  }
}

pr$registerHooks(
  list(
    preroute = function() {
      # Start timer for log info
      tictoc::tic()
    },
    postroute = function(req, res) {
      end <- tictoc::toc(quiet = TRUE)
      # Log details about the request and the response
      log_info('{convert_empty(as.character(req$HEADERS["authorization"]))} {convert_empty(req$HTTP_TENANT)} {convert_empty(req$REMOTE_ADDR)} {convert_empty(req$HTTP_USER_AGENT)} {convert_empty(req$HTTP_HOST)} {convert_empty(req$REQUEST_METHOD)} {convert_empty(req$PATH_INFO)} {convert_empty(res$status)} {round(end$toc - end$tic, digits = getOption("digits", 5))}')
    }
  )
)

pr
```

In the console, you can do:

```
pr$run()
```

so serve your API locally.

From there, go to the terminal in RStudio and do a curl. Assuming is your port, an example would be:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer my_token" -H "TENANT: 123" -X POST "http://127.0.0.1:9520/sum?a=1&b=2"
```

You should see a return of `3` in the terminal, and if you look at the R console, you will see the Authorization and tenant headers logged

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out my specific problem was actually the format of tenant name, e.g. `req$HTTP_TENANT = "Company A/S"`. When this is passed by log_info, it gets split into two columns, which is more than the logging table expects. Maybe the forward slash is escaping something.

For some reason, you have to put it in quotes in log_info, so `log_info('"{convert_empty(req$HTTP_TENANT)}"')` instead of `log_info('{convert_empty(req$HTTP_TENANT)}')` as with `req$HTTP_USER_AGENT` in [the original post](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2019/08/13/plumber-logging/).